# Connect multiple computers with sockets (python)

Tags: python, sockets, client, host

I am trying to connect multiple computers with sockets. I can run host and client on my computer, and they will connect. But if i try to run client on another computer, it wont connect. This is my host code:

```py
import socket
import requests

# NOTES:socket.gethostname()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1234))
s.listen(5)
print("Searching for available computers...")
while True:
                clientsocket, address = s.accept()
                print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")
                usr = input("Temporary username for this session: ")
                msg = input("Send to client: ")
                clientsocket.send(bytes(usr + " says > " + msg, "utf-8"))
                break

while True:
        msg1 = input("Send to client: ")
        clientsocket.send(bytes(usr + " says > " +msg1, "utf-8"))
#w
```

and this is my code for client:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))

while True:
    msg = s.recv(1028)
    print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

what is wrong?

Comment: does it throw an error of any kind?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the IP address the server is listening on, is 0.0.0.0 (localhost) only programs on the same computer can access that IP address. Change the IP address from the server to `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` that will return the local IP address of your computer. And that local IP address can be accessed by anyone, who is connected to the same network. In the code of the client, you have to change the IP address to the IP address, returned from the function above. So run `print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))`on the server computer and set the IP address the client is connecting to, to the printed value.

Comment: so instead of s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1234)), it would be s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())))?

Comment: Yes replace the '0.0.0.0' with the Line i sent

Comment: So: s.bind(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 1234)

Comment: I did this, but the other computer still gives me an error when I run client.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to put the two arguments into a tuple, sorry: s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 1234))

Comment: I did that, but it gives me the connection error when i run client.

Comment: Ok... Maybe this will help you out: https://youtu.be/3QiPPX-KeSc

Comment: Ive seen many tutorials like this, does it eventually show them connecting between two computers or just running them through one. Because mine will run through one computer just fine.

Comment: I found your code working, if I typed my IP address, got from the ipconfig command in windows, into the server code, and by typing the same IP address into the clients code

Comment: Did you do it with two computers? Because if so, maybe one of my computers is blocking the port.

Comment: Yes, did it with my windows laptop and my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

The "0.0.0.0" part is correct (keep in mind that this config allows any ip address to connect to the server (from WAN and from LAN)).
You have to change this:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))

while True:
    msg = s.recv(1028)
    print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

into this:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("ip of the server", 1234))

while True:
    msg = s.recv(1028)
    print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

Because the `socket.gethostname()` command is meant to get the ip address of the machine you are running the program on (not the server itself... infact if not specified there is no way the client can know on what address the server is located)

p.s.
remember to open port 1234 on the server machine
+
please don't use 1028... that's a very bad number: use 1024 instead

Comment: when i run the client on another computer, it says connection was refused.

Comment: this is my code so far, and it is saying the connection is refused. Maybe the computers are blocking the ports?
instead of s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1234)) in host, i have s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 1234)). Still gives me the refused to connect error on the other computer when I run client.

Comment: if you look at the socket documentation it says:  socket.gethostname(): Return a string containing the hostname of the machine where the Python interpreter is currently executing.
So it's clearly returning the address of the client machine therefore not what you want.
I guess the server has port 1234 closed.
Are you running both server and client on the same network LAN?
p.s. If you are in a LAN network the server address should be something like 192.168.1.xxx (you should not use the public ip)

Comment: Both computers are on the same wifi/network. I think the ports are closed.